# Why does using setViewControllers remove everything from the UINavigationController's nav bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Here's the issue. I use the following code in a `UINavigationController` to swap the `rootViewController`. I need to be able to swap the `rootViewController` between a number of different screens and allow the user to drill down from each screen (which is obviously why I need the Nav Controller):

```
SomeViewController *tmp = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil];
NSArray * viewControllers = [self viewControllers];
NSArray * newViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tmp, nil];
[self setViewControllers:newViewControllers];
```

Now in reading through the class reference for the `UINavigationController` I saw that for the "viewControllers" property it says: "the root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array."

When I print a count of my viewControllers array there, I get 1, the current rootViewController. Should there not be something in there for the top controller (which I assume to be the nav bar)?

As soon as I use `setViewControllers` with the new view, everything in my nav bar disappears. I'll add that I have a left and right button as well as a custom title button which are all initialized and added to the nav bar in the init method and have been working fine until they disappeared on me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Because UINavigationController manages a stack (array) of view controllers, if you were to provide it a stack, it would deallocate and remove it's old stack.  If you need to add multiple view controllers, you can use `-pushViewController:animated:completion:` with animated set to NO for all but the last view controller.

Because the stack you gave it contained only one view controller, `-count` would print 1, and it would, in fact, be the top view controller.

Comment: This is correct. In addition, the nav bar is just part of the navigation controller that can show information about the current (topmost) view controller. It isn't a view controller that has been pushed onto the stack.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. That said, speaking solely in terms or swapping the rootViewController (bottom most view controller on the stack) in and our with different view controllers. How would you handle it? I believe I understand what you're telling me but am unsure if there's a solution to my problem that I can pull from that.

Also, why would altering the viewControllers property with a new stack containing just one view controller result in all my nav bar contents disappear if the viewControllers property isn't tied to the nav bar.

Comment: To address both points: 1) if you need to swap the root view controller, doing what you're doing is actually the way to go about it.  2)  The view controller's property works like any other setter in any other language (deallocate the old, retain the new, maybe process the new).  Like I said, if you need to push multiple view controllers, push them without animation.